# Apache Tomcat access denied error in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server

- Is there is a constraint that Apache Tomcat should always be run as administrator?
- I installed it and run it in administrator account in Windows XP. It works fine.
- But in standard user account, an error message appears as 'Access Denied'.
- Apache tomcat version 6.0 ad 7.0 both shows same error.
- I have tried the solution [from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028274/unable-to-open-the-service-tomcat7). But in XP SP3, there is no such thing as 'Privilege Level' under the tab 'Compatibility'.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO] questions [Unable to open the service 'Tomcat7'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12028274) and [Tomcat 6 in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3207281)

Comment: I have already tried those solutions but they seems different from mine

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and tell us what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: When is the error message displayed? Have you looked in the [tomcat log files](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/introduction-logging-tomcat-7) for any more information?

Comment: 'Unable to start the service' is the error

Answer (score 0):

#### Common Errors and How To Fix Them

> Although Tomcat set-up for Windows environments seems fairly
>   straightforward, there are a number of issues can trip up new users
>   unfamiliar with the way that Windows handles permissions and
>   dependencies.  Here are a few common problems experienced by
>   Windows-based Tomcat users and how to work around them. UAC
>   Permissions Problems
>
> UAC, or user access control, is used by some versions of Windows to
>   restrict access to programs that could potentially make a system
>   vulnerable to malicious users.  As a web server, Tomcat falls under
>   this umbrella.
>
> If you encounter any errors relating to lack of permissions, make sure
>   that you right-click all Tomcat-related programs and choose "Run As
>   Administrator".  This is necessary even if you are logged in as an
>   administrator, due to the way that Windows handles user roles.
>
> Alternatively, you can disable UAC altogether:
>
> 1. Open the Start Menu and choose "Run".  Enter "MSCONFIG" and hit Enter to open the System Configuration utility.
> 2. Find "Disable UAP" under the "Tools Tab", select it, and click Launch.

Source [Apache Tomcat Windows Quick Start Guide](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-windows)